# Routing for multi level `slug` url structure with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, hierarchy

In my app, I have a hierarchy of categories. Each category has a slug defined in the category entity. What I am trying to achieve is hierarchical structure of the url as well to match the hierarchy of categories.
The resulting page is the landing page of last category in the url.

The app is written with React (with React router).

So, for example I have categories:

- category-1
- category-2

The url to category 2 should be:
`/category-1/category-2`

At this point I am digging for a solution and I can really find any best practices to achieve that.

The only thing that I found is `recursive paths` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths

This works from a routes perspective, but in this example, the component is actually rendered many times. How do I render it only for the last slug?

Or, am I even in the right direction here? What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Since routes are regular React components, they may be rendered anywhere in the app, including in child elements.

[example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) may help you .